# Call to undefined function odbc_connect() in Ubuntu

Tags: php, sql-server, apache, ubuntu, odbc

I am trying to connect with PHP to SQL server. I have installed Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server and I have test it using 'isql' command. Now when I am trying to connect to the server in PHP it always crashes and says "http error 500". Here is the code:

```
<?php
$server = merkur.edikt.local;
$database = ITServiceE;
$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={ODBC DRIVER 13 for SQL Server};
    Server=$server;Database=$database;", 
    'user', 
    'PW'
);
echo "connected";
?>
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 server and Apache2 and PHP 7. 
I think it might be problem with permissions for the Apache(if the Apache can access the ODBC Driver) but I am not really sure how this works. 
EDIT:
Here is the log from Apache errors:

```
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant merkur - assumed 'merkur' in         /var/www/html/index.php on line 2
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant edikt - assumed 'edikt' in /var/www/html/index.php on line 2
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant local - assumed 'local' in /var/www/html/index.php on line 2
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant ITServiceE - assumed 'ITServiceE' in /var/www/html/index.php on line 3
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function odbc_connect() in /var/www/html/index.php:4\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/index.php on line 4
```

and the file odbc.ini is empty and odbcinst.ini looks like this:

```
[ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.0.so.0.0
Threading=1
UsageCount=2
```

Comment: Have you looked at the Apache logs? (`/var/log/apache2/error.log` is the default location for Apache errors to be logged on Ubuntu 16.04) Can you edit your question and show what you have in your `/etc/odbc.ini` and `/etc/odbcinst.ini` files?

Comment: thanks for hint, I have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Call to undefined function `odbc_connect()`* means that your PHP system doesn't have any function with that name.

Since it isn't a user function written in pure PHP but a function from a PHP extension, that means that you haven't installed [such extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.uodbc.php). It's worth noting that the PHP extensions is not the same as the SQL Server driver (you need *both*).

Your code also contains some undefined constants which I guess are meant to be strings. I strongly recommend you enable full error reporting in your development box so you don't need to check the error logs to learn about simple errors.

Comment: Thank you for your advice but I have searched the Internet and I still do not understand how to install the [extension](http://php.net/manual/en/odbc.installation.php). Could you please help me even with this?

Comment: Never mind I finally found it out. I just sudo apt-get install php7.0-odbc